# 'Reviews completed' what does this status mean in springer

Tags: publications

I have submitted revision of my paper at the end of last month and status changed from Reviewers assigned to under review and now since 6 days it is showing reviews completed. Anybody has experience with this kind?

Answer (score 0):

Now the editor or associate editor has to take a decision on your paper based on the received reviews.